# Is it possible to set variable in a before, and reference in a beforeEach in a Cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress, token

I have a scenario I'm writing an automated test for.  Currently the backend for a new api is not built out, but modules for the front end of the new experience are functioning.  I want to write a test for the new experience so it's ready when we are switching to the new api.  The new api has enough function to be authenticated via jwt token, and show a validation in console.  The problem I'm having is that it works, but is not efficient.

Currently, I am using a beforeEach() block to get the authorized jwt token via POST request.  The access token taken from there is used to go to a url, then set the token in session storage.  After which, the page with expected content loads.

In context blocks, I validate the expectation of each page (There are 3 for this specific test flow).  I would like to make it so that I only hit the API and return the jwt token once, then can call that jwt token for each time the browser is loaded.

Things I have tried:

- making a before() section that creates the jwt token.  Referenced in the beforeEach section.  Result is referenceError, oc_token is not defined
- trying let instead of const; same result as above
- instead of const; using response.body.access_token.invoke('oc_token').as('oc_token'), and calling it in the beforeEach as this.oc_token; response was typeError - response.body.access.invoke is not a function
- setting variable as cy.wrap(response.body.access_token).as('oc_token'); calling as this.oc_token; response was TypeErrorcannot read properties of undefined (reading 'oc_token')
- setting variable as cy.fixture(response.body.access_token).as('oc_token'); calling as either this.oc_token, or just oc_token.  result is Error ENAMETOOLING: name too long

Current structure of test file:

```
describe('New experience test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.interceptFeatureFlags({
      'new-experience-feature-flags': true
    })

    cy.visit(Cypress.config('baseUrl'));
    cy.window().then(w => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'yadda',
        headers: 'stuff',
        body: { payload }
      }).then((response) => {
        expect.(response).property('status').to.equal(200)
        const oc_token = response.body.access_token;
        w.sessionStorage.setItem(
          'jwt',
          oc_token
        )
        w.sessionStorage.setItem(
          'other_jwt',
          oc_token
        )
      })
    });
    cy.fixture('new_experience_context.json').then((context) => {
      button(cy).click();
    });
  });

  context('first page', () => {
    it('shows condition', () => {
      thing.should('exist');
    });

  context('second page', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      //steps that get to the second page
    });

    it('shows condition', () => {
      thing.should('exist');
    });
  });

  context('third page', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      //steps that get to the second page
      //steps that get to the third page
    });

    it('shows condition', () => {
      thing.should('exist');
    });
  });
});

//functions that identify things in the DOM
```

Structure I've tried:

```
describe('New experience test', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'yadda',
    headers: 'stuff',
    body: { payload }
   }).then((response) => {
    expect.(response).property('status').to.equal(200)
    const oc_token = response.body.access_token;
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.interceptFeatureFlags({
      'new-experience-feature-flags': true
    })

    cy.visit(Cypress.config('baseUrl'));
    cy.window().then(w => {
        w.sessionStorage.setItem(
          'jwt',
          oc_token
        )
        w.sessionStorage.setItem(
          'other_jwt',
          oc_token
        )
      })
    });
    cy.fixture('new_experience_context.json').then((context) => {
      button(cy).click();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you can do this by declaring the variable in an outer context, the variable will be a "closure" variable.

```js
describe('New experience test', () => {

  let oc_token;

  before(() => {
    cy.request({...}).then((response) => {
      oc_token = response.body.access_token; // set outer ("closure") variable
    })
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.interceptFeatureFlags({...})

    cy.visit('/')                 // uses baseUrl from config
      .then(w => {
        w.sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', oc_token)
        w.sessionStorage.setItem('other_jwt', oc_token)
      })
    ...
  })
})
```

The only problem you might have is if Cypress resets the browser, but it's unlikely if you are visiting `baseUrl` set in configuration.

There are other methods such as `alias`

```js
describe('New experience test', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.request({...}).then((response) => {
      cy.wrap(response.body.access_token).as('oc_token');  // alias variable
    })
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.interceptFeatureFlags({...})

    cy.visit('/')                 // uses baseUrl from config
      .then(w => {
        cy.get('@oc_token').then(oc_token => {     // retrieve alias value
          w.sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', oc_token)
          w.sessionStorage.setItem('other_jwt', oc_token)
        })
      })
    ...
  })
})
```

or environment variable

```js
describe('New experience test', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.request({...}).then((response) => {
      Cypress.env('oc_token', response.body.access_token); // env variable
    })
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.interceptFeatureFlags({...})

    cy.visit('/')                 // uses baseUrl from config
      .then(w => {
        w.sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', Cypress.env('oc_token'))
        w.sessionStorage.setItem('other_jwt', Cypress.env('oc_token'))
      })
    ...
  })
})
```

Comment: That was successful thank you